# Android MapView animateTo and zoomIn in the same time

Tags: java, android, android-mapview

How can I call animateTo and zoomIn for Map View Controller at the same time to get beautiful animation like Google Maps on double click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method of MapController, it called [zoomInFixing](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapController.html#zoomInFixing%28int,%20int%29). It do what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Well is not supported zoomIn and animateTo are async and independant. You must animate a little bit then zoomin a little bit, animate a bit more , zoom a bit more with this sequence. To do that you must calculate yourself the animateTo steps and do that animate zoom sequence to achieve this smooth animation.